# SIP 200 OK to INVITE followed by 100 Trying

Tags: sip

1. Alice --- INVITE (SDP) --> Bob
2. Alice <-- 100 Trying --- Bob
3. Alice <-- 200 OK (SDP) --- Bob

What can be the reason of missing 18x response before 200 OK ?
Is this a normal scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since a provisional response (1xx) is optional the answerer can reply directly by sending a final response (2xx). An example of such a case is where the answerer is an application and not a human. There is no need to have the target phone ringing when an automated process handles the incoming call.

More information can be found in RFC3261 and especially [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3261#section-13.3.1.1)

Comment: Sure. Thank you. 
There wasn't real answer from "real Bob".